# Find which Event was Fired

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am attempting to capture which Event was fired.  I have two events that point to the same function, `CurrentLoan_LogEntryEvent`. Inside `CurrentLoan_LogEntryEvent`, how do I determine which Event was actually fired: `LogEntryAdded` or `LogEntryChange`.

Below you'll find sample of my code how I have it now. Let me know if you have any questions about my code.

`CurrentLoan` is a `Loan` object, which has two events.

```
public MyApplication()
{
    ThirdPartyDLL.LoanOpened += new EventHandler(CurrentLoanOpened);
}

private void CurrentLoanOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ThirdPartyDLL.CurrentLoan.LogEntryAdded += CurrentLoan_LogEntryEvent;
    ThirdPartyDLL.CurrentLoan.LogEntryChange += CurrentLoan_LogEntryEvent;
}

private void CurrentLoan_LogEntryEvent(object sender, LogEntryEventArgs e)
{
    // When LogEntry was Added or Changed.
    // How do I determine if LogEntryAdded or LogEntryChange was fired?
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I'll have to look for it. The simplest option is to use subscribe with a lambda expression which calls the common method, passing in an appropriate value. Are you sure `LogEntryEventArgs` doesn't contain the information you need anyway though?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to differentiate two events, no point in attaching a single method for multiple events. Give them different handlers.

You typically attach single handler for multiple events when you don't care about where the event origin, but you always wanted to do the same thing in the handler.

If you have some common logic to be executed, you can call it inside the handlers.

```
private void CurrentLoanOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ThirdPartyDLL.CurrentLoan.LogEntryAdded += CurrentLoan_LogEntryAdded;
    ThirdPartyDLL.CurrentLoan.LogEntryChange += CurrentLoan_LogEntryChange;
}

private void CurrentLoan_LogEntryAdded(object sender, LogEntryEventArgs e)
{
    //LogEntryAdded fired
    YourOptionalCommonMethodIfAny();
}

private void CurrentLoan_LogEntryChange(object sender, LogEntryEventArgs e)
{
    //LogEntryChange fired
    YourOptionalCommonMethodIfAny();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you simply do this:

```
private void CurrentLoanOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ThirdPartyDLL.CurrentLoan.LogEntryAdded += CurrentLoan_LogEntryAddedEvent;
    ThirdPartyDLL.CurrentLoan.LogEntryChange += CurrentLoan_LogEntryChangeEvent;
}

private void CurrentLoan_LogEntryAddedEvent(object sender, LogEntryEventArgs e)
{
    // First do what you must do specifically for added events
    CurrentLoan_LogEntry(e);
}


private void CurrentLoan_LogEntryChangeEvent(object sender, LogEntryEventArgs e)
{
    // First do what you must do specifically for changed events
    CurrentLoan_LogEntry(e);
}
```

Binding one handler to multiple events and then figuring out what to do inside that handler is just overcomplicating things.

Always keep your code as simple to understand and change as possible.